# Word 2013 - How to add figures to Visio Diagrams in Word Document

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, microsoft-word-2013, caption

I am trying to add a figure caption to a Visio diagram that I have inserted into a word document and I am having some trouble.    For example, if I right click on any inserted image in my word document, I get an option in the context menu to Insert Caption

[image: insert caption example]

However, for any Visio diagrams that I paste into my document, I do not see an Insert Caption option in the right click context menu.

[image]

I would like the Visio diagrams to be editable by anyone who has Visio installed on their PC from within the Word document itself.   I do not seem to have this issue if I do a paste special (CTRL+E, S) and choose bitmap or any other option.    Any idea how to resolve this issue?

- My Operating System is Windows 7 x64 Enterprise
- Visio Professional 2010
- Microsoft Office Word 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I only have Visio 2010 and Word 2010, but I hope some of this translates to Word 2013 decently.

First off, instead of copying and pasting the Visio diagram from Visio into Word, have you tried dragging and dropping the Visio diagram file itself into the Word document?

Next, I would try to embed the existing Visio diagram into your document.  Insert > Object > Create from File > Browse to file > Check "Link to File" > "OK"

If you're looking to make the file such that your co-workers can edit within Word when Visio is installed, you may need to create a new Visio embedded object within Word.  Try going to Insert > Object > Create New > Microsoft Visio Drawing > "OK".  Then you will need to copy and paste your existing Visio diagrams into the newly created embedded object.

Hopefully one of these will get the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Dude!   You got it!   It says I cannot award the bounty for another 4 hours, but rest assured that I will award the bounty later on today!   Dragging and dropping worked!  Thank you so much for your valuable input on this question.

Comment: @Richie086 - Thanks man.  Glad I could help you out!